# Subtract the mean of a group for a column away from a column value

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

I have a companies dataset with 35 columns. The companies can belong to one of 8 different groups. How do I for each group create a new dataframe which subtract the mean of the column for that group away from the original value?

Here is an example of part of the dataset.

[image]

So for example for row 1 I want to subtract the mean of BANK_AND_DEP for Consumer Markets away from the value of 7204.400207. I need to do this for each column.

I assume this is some kind of combination of a transform and a lambda - but cannot hit the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might seem counter-intuitive for this to involve a loop at all, looping through the columns themselves allows you to do this as a vectorized operation, which will be quicker than `.apply()`. For what to subtract by, you'll combine `.groupby()` and `.transform()` to get the value you need to subtract from a column. Then, just subtract it.

```
for column in df.columns:
    df['new_'+column] = df[column]-df.groupby('Cluster')['column'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I have tried  the above code and am getting the KeyError 'Column not found: column'.